# How to add a CAPTCHA to all forms for specific IP address with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications, security, captcha

I have table that track users and IP address' actions and mark them as spammers if some conditions occurs.

I want to add a CAPTCHA field to all forms when the user or IP address is marked as a spammer.

What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use custom form builder with your custom behaviour for 'spammers'. Check this out: 
[Form builder](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/form-builders-in-rails.html)